# Why does copying to computer from my Nikon D7000 abruptly stop?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d7000, sdcard, usb, file-transfer

I have a Nikon D7000 which I bought recently. Camera captures all the images properly. But when I connect the USB cable and try to copy the images from the camera to my Laptop, it starts normally, but all of a sudden photos stopping getting copied properly and copies only half of what is there in the card to my computer. When I try to copy missed ones again, it copies a very few photos and keeps abruptly stopping (copying of images). I have to do this till I copy all the photos. This doesn't seem to happen when I directly try to copy from the SD card.

I have checked my cable which seems to be fine. Also my camera battery is good.

Is there a issue with Nikon D7000 or am I missing some step while copying the images from camera? Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: I had the exact same symptoms with an Olympus compact when connected it to a WinXP computer. Maybe not the same cause, but same symptoms. I never figured it out, so I just used a card reader instead of connecting the camera in.

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshooting like this is basically a matter of changing one variable at a time. Trying to directly copy from the SD card is a good first step, and testing the cable is good too. I'd still suspect that the cable is the problem, but if you're sure it's not that, it may be either a problem with your laptop's USB port or a software problem on the computer. Have you tried another computer?

All that said, since taking out the SD card works, I'd go with that. A good card reader will be often faster than the camera's conection anyway. More at: [Is it better to transfer photos by removing the memory card or by directly using a data cable?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14669/is-it-better-to-transfer-photos-by-removing-the-memory-card-or-by-directly-using)

Comment: Thanks a answering mattdm. I had got the camera from an online shop. I was just worried whether this was an issue with the camera. My brother has a Nikon too. I will try to use another cable and then post the result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer, but in my case (Windows 7, Nikon D5100), copying from the camera to the computer stops if I open an image directly from the camera.
So, I'm not multitasking - I wait until all the pictures in the current folder are read and all the visible picture files have their thumbnail visible (it takes a while for a full folder, 1000 pictures), and only after that I select what I want and copy to PC.
After the copying is done, I will disconnect camera and look at pictures.

EDIT: Try to not start copying until all the pictures are visible with valid thumbnails.